# Run Code On Application Close

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

This is a very common problem yet again, and yet again it seems there is no real support in E4 (but if I remember correctly, it did not work in E3 either).

I want to close my database connection when the application closes. Or more general: I want to do any kind of clean up on exit.

So the usual API for this is:

```
public class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor {

    public ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(final IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
        super(configurer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preWindowShellClose() {
        if (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindowCount() <= 1) {
            // the last window is about to close
            Datababase.close();
        }
        return super.preWindowShellClose();
    }
}
```

The problem? It's not called every time the application closes, especially not on `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close();` (even though the JavaDoc claims this method closes the windows).

*(If you want to test if this claim is correct, just use the `ExitHandler` to close your application - `preWindowShellClose()` is not called then.)*

I could create my own handler and manually call the clean up methods yet again, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Another way you could react to a application shutdown is the [Shutdown Hooks API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    Datababase.close();
}));
```

Problem: for an RCP application, this hook is called way, way, way too late, e.g. all plug-ins are already closed then.

I feel there must be a simple (and working) way, I just haven't found it yet. If it's important, we are using the Lesser Evil Eclipse (aka E3 compatibility).

How do I run code whenever an application closes?

Comment: Did you try `IWorkbench::addWindowListener` or `IWorkbench::addWorkbenchListener`? If these don't work reliably either, you may consider running the clean up code from you bundle's `stop` method. Sorry, that I can only guess here...

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann No, I did not try these. And both seem to work. So I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IWorkbench::addWindowListener` or `IWorkbench::addWorkbenchListener` to get notified when a workbench window is closed or the workbench is shut down.

You may also consider running the clean up code from you bundle's `stop` method.